# Filter expression based on a nested attribute in an array - DynamoDB

Tags: javascript, amazon-dynamodb

I have a DynamoDB table where I store this data;

[JSON data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iO17.png)

where "device" is the partition key and "datetime" the sort key.
I'm able to query data based on PartitionKey and range of dates (sort key). But now, I would need to filter based on "endpoint" which is inside "data" which is an array. For example, I would like to retrieve the data only if endpoint 1 exist in data array, or for example if endpoint IN (1,3) exist.
I 'm using following code;

```html
var dev = event.params.querystring.device;    
var from = event.params.querystring.from;
var to  = event.params.querystring.to;
var ascord = event.params.querystring.ascord;
var limit = event.params.querystring.limit;

  
var qryParams = {
  TableName : "mytable",
  KeyConditionExpression: "#id = :dddd and #tm between :time1 and :time2",
  FilterExpression: "data.endpoint = :ep",
  ExpressionAttributeNames:{
      "#id": "device",
      "#tm": "datetime"
  },
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":dddd": dev,
      ":time1": from, 
      ":time2": to, 
      ":ep": 1
  }
};

docClient.query(qryParams, function(err, data){
    if (err){
        callback(err, null);
    }else {
        callback(null, data);
    }
})
```

But it doesn't retrieve any record. I also tried to use placeholders (#data.#endpoint) but didn't work.
What would be the right way to do it?
Also, should I create an index in the table for the endpoints?

Thanks for your help.
Regards;
Gus

Answer (score 3):

The attribute `data` is a list of objects. So, DynamoDB can't find the item if you don't provide the array index of the list attribute. You can use `contains` function, if you know the value of `endpoint` and `value`.

**Option 1 - Using contains:-**

```
var params = {
    TableName: table,
    KeyConditionExpression: "#id = :dddd and #tm between :time1 and :time2",
    FilterExpression: "contains (#data, :ep)",
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        "#id": "deviceid",
        "#tm": "datetime",
        "#data" : "data"
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":dddd": "1",
        ":time1": "2017-08-22T00:44:11:424Z",
        ":time2": "2017-08-22T23:44:11:424Z",
        ":ep": {
            "endpoint": 1,
            "value": "23"
        }
    }
};
```

**Option 2 - Using Index :-**

```
var params = {
    TableName: table,
    KeyConditionExpression: "#id = :dddd and #tm between :time1 and :time2",
    FilterExpression: "#data"+"[0].endpoint = :ep",
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        "#id": "deviceid",
        "#tm": "datetime",
        "#data" : "data"
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":dddd": "1",
        ":time1": "2017-08-22T00:44:11:424Z",
        ":time2": "2017-08-22T23:44:11:424Z",
        ":ep": 1
    }
};
```

Comment: Not working for me {
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
   //":templateType": useCase,
   ":deliveryStatus": {
    eventType: deliveryStatus
   }
 
  },
  FilterExpression: "contains (timestampList, :deliveryStatus)", 
  Select: "COUNT",
  TableName: "waas-messageDetails-"+env.stage,
 };